# Repetitive cache observable in Rxjava, android lifecycle and cache operator

Tags: android, rx-java

Huy guys. I am new with those RxJava topics. I am working with the cache operator in order to re-register a subscriber if the device experiment a configuration change. My problem is that every time that the cache observable receive a subscription, the observable starts all the process again.

I know that all cache observable holes the emitted items in memory to avoid restart the task and just emit the cache items to new subscribers. But what is happening to me is that I have a task running in the background, the task progress is notify to the user through a progress bar which receives that progress through an cache observable. When I rotate the device and I do the subscription again, all the task start again. I just want to keep from the point it is after experiment the configuration change.

Comment: To be of more assistance we do require some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need a mechanism to persist the Observable during screen rotations, the `cache()` operator only works that that Observable instance.

I recommend using a retained fragment to hold onto your Observables.  You could also use a static HashMap to store Observables, but you need to be extra careful about cleaning them up.

Comment: Hi guys, Thank you very much for replay back to my request. But I was missing an important part in my implementation, I wasn't reusing the same observable I was caching and saving at the same time. So everything worked ok.